# Is there a way to migrate devices from one enterprise to another?

Tags: android-management-api

Currently I had few devices on an Enterprise that I've spun up myself in GCloud but would like to know whether there's possibility to migrate these devices to say Google Endpoint Management or another EMM provider, is there any possibility of this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using AMAPI.  However, we have filed a feature request on your behalf but there is no guarantee if/when this will be worked on.

I suggest joining the [Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to keep you posted on the latest updates.